# Visual Studio 2017 package tab is missing in project settings

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget, visual-studio-2017

I created a simple library .NET Framework project.

I would like to generate NuGet packages after build as described [here](https://blog.nuget.org/20170316/NuGet-now-fully-integrated-into-MSBuild.html).

However, the Package tab is missing, here is a screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: that link is all about .NET Core projects, not traditional .NET Framework

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Visual Studio 2017 package tab is missing in project settings

That because your project is library .NET Framework, which still using `packages.config` to manage NuGet packages. And Package tab is only supported by the new nuget package management form: **PackageReference**.

`.NET Standard` class library or `.NET Core` projects come with PackageReference enabled by default. So **you can create .NET Standard class library or .NET Core project**, then you will see `Package` tab on the properties window.

If you want to use the Package tab for library .NET Framework project, you can **convert your project from the old .csproj to new .csproj**, (Right click your project->Unload project->Edit .csproj. Replace the contents of your csproj with the following:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net46</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

See [Old csproj to new csproj: Visual Studio 2017 upgrade guide](http://www.natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/03/09/vs2015-to-vs2017-upgrade/) for more info about convert old .csproj to new .csproj.

Note: Need to delete the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file in the Properties.

After convert to new .csproj, you will get the Package tab for library .NET Framework project:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this is one part of the solution. After i have tried your tips the package tab still disappears. I uninstalled Visual Studio and reinstalled it. It still not appears. Then i installed the Visual Studio Feature "Datenspeicherung and -verarbeitung". Then finally the tab appears.
Thank you for you help!

Comment: Which translates to "Data storage and processing" in English.

Comment: Is this specific to .NET4.6 then ? Or can I try it with .NET 4 based project?