# Visual studio does not show Packages tab anymore

Tags: visual-studio

I have been building a Class Library (.NET Standard) with Visual Studio 2017. Now that I am ready to publish it to NuGet I went to the properties screen to try to fill out the package information.

For some reason, the Packages tab no longer appears. It had previously when I was first setting up the package.

[image: Class library no longer shows packages tab]

I went through the steps in this [Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47283750/visual-studio-2017-package-tab-is-missing-in-project-settings) and it still does not appear. I also tried creating a new class library with both .NET Standard and .NET Framework and it does not appear there either.

Does anyone know what might have happened or how to resolve this?

`.csproj` file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>ClickATel</RootNamespace>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <Authors>Marcello Bachechi</Authors>
    <Product>Click A Tell</Product>
    <PackageId>ClickATellAPI</PackageId>
    <Description>This is an unoffical Click A Tell platform API for .NET
Allows 
- Checking account Balance
- Sending Text Messages
- Checking Text Status</Description>
    <PackageIconUrl>https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/7206811?s=280&amp;v=4</PackageIconUrl>
    <Version>1.0.1</Version>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>1.0.0.0</FileVersion>
    <ApplicationIcon />
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <StartupObject />
    <RepositoryUrl>https://github.com/pilotkid/Click-A-Tell-.NET</RepositoryUrl>
    <RepositoryType>GIT</RepositoryType>
    <Copyright>2019 Marcello Bachechi</Copyright>
    <PackageProjectUrl>https://github.com/pilotkid/Click-A-Tell-.NET</PackageProjectUrl>
    <PackageLicenseExpression></PackageLicenseExpression>
    <PackageRequireLicenseAcceptance>true</PackageRequireLicenseAcceptance>
    <PackageLicenseFile>v0.9.txt</PackageLicenseFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="newtonsoft.json" Version="12.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Properties\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="..\v0.9.txt">
      <Pack>True</Pack>
      <PackagePath></PackagePath>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

---

**Update** I tried opening the package in VS 2019. It did have the package tab.

Comment: When I upgraded to VS 2019 this issue went away. Seems to be just a bug in 2017